# Are there any corelation between Android OS version and supported Google play services version?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, crashlytics

Firebase Crashlytics has announced that it's going to remove its old version and we should use its new version SDK till november 15th on our androird app. To do so, we should also increase our minimum supported google play services version to at lease 16 which currently is 11.xx.xx.
So the question is what android devices don't support google play services v 16.xx.xx? I need to know this so I can estimate our users churn.
Are there any relations between minimum google play services version and Android OS version or Android API level or Device model?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any relations between minimum google play services version and Android OS version or Android API level or Device model?

As with any other unknown app, just peek its Manifest. If there's limitation on sdk, it will be there as well.

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is what android devices don't support google play services v 16.xx.xx?

That's going to be an extremely long list of devices that are mostly no longer in use any more.  It's probably not worthwhile to try to get this list, as it's going to take so much work to process what that means for you.  It's probably better to take the advice of Android Studio (during new project configuration) when it says that "your app will run on approximately 99.8% of devices" when targeting api level 16.  According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview):

> In general, devices running Android 4.1 (API level 16) or later and have the Google Play services app installed receive updates within a few days. This allows you to use the newest APIs in Google Play services and reach most of the devices in the Android ecosystem. Devices older than Android 4.1 or devices without the Google Play services app are not supported.

> Are there any relations between minimum google play services version and Android OS version or Android API level or Device model?

Play services currently keeps itself up to date on all devices that target API level 16 or higher.

If you want to fully understand all the documentation details about the relationship between Play services and Android API levels, you should [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk).  Play services doesn't target anything about specific devices or models.  It is purely dependent on API level.